# How do you calculate a result from a listbox selection in Visual Basic? (The data in the listbox is being read off a text file)

Tags: vb.net, listbox, project

So I am asked in school to create a Railway Ticketing System program that will allow you to buy either a single or return ticket and based off that the cost will be displayed. The information of all destinations is to be read via a text file. The text file is given below:

```
Knapford , 1
Crosby , 8
Weltworth , 15
Maron , 23
Cronk , 28
Kildane , 31
Keltthorpe Road , 46
Crovan's Gate , 56
Vicarstown , 76
Barrow , 77
```

I have managed to separate the integers from the destination names via the code below which then is displayed in a listbox:

```
Public Class PurchaseScreen
Dim Filename As String
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Filename = "StationFile.txt"
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("StationFile.txt")
    Dim Word As String = ""
    Dim Words(11) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until sr.Peek = -1

        'grab one word at a time from the text file
        Word = sr.ReadLine()

        'place word into array
        Words(i) = Word

        'increment array counter
        i = i + 1

    Loop

    Return
End Sub
```

The problem I am facing is that I am trying to access the numbers that were omitted by the code, since only the destination name can be displayed in the listbox. How do I go about using those numbers to perform my calculations?

Comment: Instead of specifying a length for your array you can use the split function so that your program remains dynamic. Also use a sub instead of a function because you are not returning any values.

Comment: So the text file is in exactly that format - on one line with no carriage returns?

Comment: or are each station name and price on their own line? e.g. Knapford , 1 (new line) Crosby , 8 (new line)

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your post so that the format of the text file is clearer to users reading your question

So to make it easier to access your data, you would be better having a `Station` structure and storing each station in list of these structures.

To populate your list, iterate through the list of stations and add the names to the list.

When an item is selected, use the selected item's index to look up the data in the stations list and there you go.

```
'obviously you need to change this path to match where your "stations.txt"file is stored
'and also possibly the name of the listbox you're populating
Dim Filename As String = "D:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\blank\blank\stations.text"
Dim selectedStation As Station

'a structure of station that can be used to store the data in the stations.txt file
'in a clearer more maintainable way
Structure Station
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Data As Single
End Structure

'list to store the data from stations.txt
Dim stations As New List(Of Station)

'your form's load event
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    stations.Clear()
    ReadStationData()
    PopulateListBox()
End Sub

Private Sub ReadStationData()
    Dim tempDataLine As String = ""
    'read all the stations.txt data into a string
    Using sr As New StreamReader(Filename)
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            tempDataLine = sr.ReadLine
            Dim newStation As Station
            Dim tempSplit() As String = tempDataLine.Split(New String() {" , "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            newStation.Name = tempSplit(0)
            newStation.Data = CSng(tempSplit(1))
            stations.Add(newStation)
        End While
    End Using
End Sub

'clear the ListBox and populate it from the Stations list
Private Sub PopulateListBox()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each stationItem As Station In stations
        ListBox1.Items.Add(stationItem.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'dummy code to show usage
    selectedStation = stations(ListBox1.SelectedIndex())
    MessageBox.Show("Selected station = " & selectedStation.Name & vbCrLf & "Station price = " & selectedStation.Data)
End Sub
```